# Can share global namespaces across .net 6 projects?

Tags: c#, .net

In .Net 6, we gained [Global Usings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#global-using-directives). I have several projects that are similar and I'd like to share the same GlobalNamespaces.cs file I've created across the projects.

I tried to add the file as a link in Visual Studio, but after removing the usings of that file, I'm getting build errors.

Is there a way to share it across projects?

An example:

- c:\myproject\src\GlobalUsings.cs
- c:\myproject\src\Project1\ (*.csproj, cs files)
- c:\myproject\src\Project2\ (*.csproj, cs files)

I want to use GlobalUsings in both.

Comment: Did you try using `<Using />` In a  [Directory.Build.props and/or Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)

Comment: This looks like a good reference as well -> https://gsferreira.com/archive/2018/06/versioning-net-core-applications-using-cake/

Comment: I didn't know about <Using />. I'll give it a shot and report back

Comment: <Using works, please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @gsferreira's [article](https://gsferreira.com/archive/2021/where-to-place-c10-global-usings/) and [a link to an example](https://github.com/justeat/httpclient-interception/blob/6e9e327f583cb1dc24459fce16d8aee754bc1caf/Directory.Build.props#L47-L54) from his [tweet](https://twitter.com/martin_costello/status/1464498288061816838)

I was able to add a Directory.Build.props file next to my .sln and it works!

```
<Project>
     <PropertyGroup>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
     </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj' AND '$(MSBuildProjectName)' != 'My.Other.Project'">
        <Using Include="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This works now!

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace Project2;
public class Class1
{
    JToken token = new JObject();

}
```

This works well for global using, but I found it was more complicated than I expected since there are some project that don't have nuget packages or other projects referenced. So the Global usings isn't really global, but more specific to what the project has referenced. If the similar projects were in a same sub folder, maybe that would work better. I haven't tried nesting Directory.Build.props files

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets was helpful as well